# Postgressql function does not accept parameter in EF core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, npgsql

If I pass values to my SP like this:

```
  var sqlpowerConv = @"SELECT * from wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv('" + dtFrom + @"','" + dtTo + @"','" + regional_managers + @"','" + service_under + @"','" + supervisor + @"')
                            res (o_availability double precision, o_production double precision,o_numberofturbines integer, o_errors_disabled integer,o_failed_battery integer,o_power integer,o_crew_present text)";
```

It works, but because of SQL injection I have to use it with Parameters:

```
 NpgsqlDate DateFrom = NpgsqlDate.Parse(dtFrom);
        NpgsqlDate DateTo = NpgsqlDate.Parse(dtTo);
        NpgsqlParameter p0 = new NpgsqlParameter("@drfrom", NpgsqlDbType.Date);
        NpgsqlParameter p1 = new NpgsqlParameter("@dtto", NpgsqlDbType.Date);
        NpgsqlParameter p2 = new NpgsqlParameter("@regionalmanager", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
        NpgsqlParameter p3 = new NpgsqlParameter("@serviceunder", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
        NpgsqlParameter p4 = new NpgsqlParameter("@supervisor", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
    
        var x = _db.dataInGlance.FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT * from wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv(@p0,@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)
                            res (o_availability double precision, o_production double precision,o_numberofturbines integer, o_errors_disabled integer,o_failed_battery integer,o_power integer,o_crew_present text)",DateFrom,DateTo,regionalManager,service_under,supervisor
                          ).ToList();
```

I'm not sure if it's the right way of passing by parameters but I get an error:

```
No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'NpgsqlDate'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: EF Core doesn't (currently) support the Npgsql-specific NpgsqlDate - is there any reason you're using that instead of DateTime (or NodaTime)?

Comment: @ShayRojansky i changed my datatype to timestamp and it works